# Microsoft Access Move Multiple Rows In Table1 To A Single Row In Table2

Tags: ms-access

I'm new to Microsoft Access so my terminolgy and understanding are limited, please bear with me. I am interfacing a piece of lab equipment via Serial/ASTM/ODBC to MS Access for Office 365 MSO 16.0.12.x.

The equipment and ASTM transmit different parameters per line via the same field names. So I end up with 23 different rows in Access and each row has a different parameter and result. I use Table1 as a queue. I need to move the captured data from multiple rows in Table1 to multiple columns in a single row in Table2. I've created a greatly simplifed version of the database to try to understand how to do this properly.  Table1 is a simplified example of captured data. Table2 is a simulated example of what I am trying to achieve. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16546305/pivoting-data-in-ms-access

Comment: Great! That was magic. I had no idea that TRANSFORM and PIVOT were available. I'll answer below to mark this as complete. TY

Answer (score 0):

With help from Jonathan Fite who pointed me in the correct direction.
Via SQL:

```
TRANSFORM FIRST(RESULTS)
SELECT RECORDNUM
FROM Table1
GROUP BY RECORDNUM
PIVOT TYPE
```

Via GUI choose Totals and Crosstab then:

[image]